# " Method is not present on Selenium interface: loadTestData" in selenium IDE for Data Driven testing

Tags: selenium, data-driven-tests

I am trying to execute data driven testing using selenium IDE.

I downloaded all the three extensions that are told step by step and uploaded to selenium IDE core extentions in the same order as guided (C:\Selenium\extentions\goto_sel_ide.js, C:\Selenium\extentions\user-extensions.js.includeCommand4IDE, C:\Selenium\extentions\datadriven.js)

I restarted the IDE to make sure that it accepts the extention files. It was done successfully.

My first command in the IDE is `loadTestData | file:///C:/Selenium Test Cases/members.xml`

When I am executing the test case I am getting error which is as follows:

> [info] Executing: |loadTestData | file:///C:/Selenium Test
>   Cases/members.xml | | [error] Method is not present on Selenium
>   interface: loadTestData

Comment: I gather that in the past year or two, there have been significant changes to the ways in which Selenium plugins are loaded. Are you trying to follow a tutorial that's out of date? Other than that, it seems like quite a few people forget to call `addPlugin()` with their plugin ID.

Comment: that might be the case , i am new at selenium and i try to look up to tutorials that are available for free online. Any good tutorial to understand selenium ide and webdriver that have been updated you know of? Any insight is appreciated, thanks!